# Is it possible to detect unknown CSS properties or invalid CSS property values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, error-handling

I lost a bit of time to find out why a web page rendered somewhat unexpectedly. It turned out that the cause was a misspelled CSS attribute name (something like `<div style='postion:absolute'>`).

I am now wondering if it is possible to detect unknown CSS properties or invalid CSS property values in JavaScript, after a document has loaded or while the CSS properties are parsed.

Comment: I actually find this question very useful. If one wants to reproduce the Dev Tools warning programmaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use an IDE/Code Editor/Text Editor.

Good IDE/Code Editor show error for such codes.

**EXAMPLE: (Code Editor: VS Code)**
[image: Better Way]

## or

You can use the browser developer tools to find errors.

**EXAMPLE: (Browser: Google Chrome)**
[image]

> #### **Both Images use your code...**